# PULP - How to get the CPLEX solver status instead of the LpStatus stauts?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

I'm using the CPLEX solver via PULP in Python. When I solve a problem with time limit, CPLEX prints to the screen the code [107](http://www-eio.upc.edu/lceio/manuals/cplex-11/html/refcallablelibrary/html/macros/CPXMIP_TIME_LIM_FEAS.html) which means "Time limit exceeded, but integer solution exists". However, if I print the status of `pulp.LpStatus[problem.status]` what I get back is the value 1 which according to pulp's [documentation](https://www.coin-or.org/PuLP/constants.html) means an optimal solution has been found, which is actually wrong.

How can I access the CPLEX status codes instead of PULP's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access CPLEX status code and status string. Consider the following example:

```
>>> import pulp 
>>> prob = pulp.LpProblem("example", pulp.LpMinimize)
>>> x = pulp.LpVariable('x', lowBound=0, upBound=1)
>>> prob+= x <= -1
```

- **Example 1** - Time limit exceeded

  ```
  >>> solver = pulp.CPLEX_PY(msg=0, timeLimit=0)
  >>> prob.setSolver(solver)
  >>> prob.solve()
  -3
  >>> solver.solverModel.solution.get_status()
  108
  >>> solver.solverModel.solution.get_status_string()
  'time limit exceeded, no integer solution'
  ```
- **Example 2** - Infeasible

  ```
  >>> solver = pulp.CPLEX_PY(msg=0)
  >>> prob.setSolver(solver)
  >>> prob.solve()
  -1
  >>> solver.solverModel.solution.get_status()
  103
  >>> solver.solverModel.solution.get_status_string()
  'integer infeasible'
  ```